# How to see Windows startup command line commands

Tags: windows-7, boot

What is the shortcut for removing the Windows boot screen logo during startup so that you can actually see all the command line commands that are running in the startup sequence?

Comment: fyi, Windows NT won't show you any "command line commands" because there aren't any. There's no `autoexec.bat`, just the kernel.

Comment: Vote to close??

Answer (score 1):

if you go into windows and run msconfig there should be an option to disable visual boot (under the boot tab called No Gui Boot). If you disable that it should let you see the text.